# HTTP Context for testing in Java Play! 2.0.2

Tags: java, http, testing, playframework, playframework-2.0

We're trying to write tests for our views, but some of them require session variables to properly render. This is what a standard test looks like:

```
@Test
public void indexTest() {
    running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Content html = views.html.index.render(loginForm);
            assertThat(contentType(html)).isEqualTo("text/html");
            assertThat(contentAsString(html)).contains("log in");
        }
    });
}
```

loginForm is a mock form we have declared in the test class.

However, when we try to run this test we get the following error:

'There is no HTTP Context available from here'

We tried using a testServer and trying to get the http context from requests to that server, but to no avail.

Thanks :-)

**Edit** @nico_ekito

This is the code surrounding my loginForm:

```
Form<Login> loginForm = Controller.form(Login.class);
```

However, I believe the problem lies within the controller being invoked, because the view doesn't use any session properties. The authenticate() method (in the controller, which is being rendered I believe when the form is submitted to the view) however, uses sessions.

Comment: Do you run your tests from play command line? I know that there may be problems if you run tests from eclipse.

Comment: Yeah, we run 'play test' in the terminal.

Comment: Please show the code around your loginForm mock.

Comment: Why do you use session in your views ? you should get your session variables in your controller and pass it explicitly to the view using parameters, no ?

Comment: As I said in the comment, we don't use session in the views ("because the view doesn't use any session properties").

Answer (score 0):

Would be helpful if you posted the entire view, because you might be using an auth plugin/i18n plugin or something like that which in turn uses session properties. You could also try mocking out the context with Mocktio or similar before running the test.

```
Context.current.set(
        new Context(mock(Request.class), 
                    new HashMap<String, String>(),  
                    new HashMap<String, String>()));
```

I would recommend going over your views one more time checking for session properties though.