# Absolute URLs in Play Framework (Java) with no HTTP context

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

In our (Java) Play app, we have an asynchronous job that sends out e-mails to users when various deadlines are passed. The e-mails are supposed contain links to relevant pages on our site. However, in such an asynchronous job, it is not possible to create absolute URLs using `routes.MyPage.myTemplate().absoluteURL()`, because there is no available HTTP context.

What is the recommended pattern to obtain absolute URLs when outside an HTTP context? For tests, one would [create a "fake" HTTP context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328951/http-context-for-testing-in-java-play-2-0-2), but I don't feel this is the right way to things in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`play.mvc.Call` has more than one version of `absoluteUrl`. There is a version like the followin:

```
/**
 * Transform this call to an absolute URL.
 *
 * @param secure true if the absolute URL should use HTTPS protocol instead of HTTP
 * @param host the absolute URL's domain
 * @return the absolute URL string
 */
public String absoluteURL(boolean secure, String host)
```

You can use it to generate absolute urls without having a request.

Comment: And how do I obtain the `host`?

Comment: I solved this by setting the host in the configuration file. You could retrieve the computer's hostname but I would go by setting it in the `application.conf`

Comment: OK; that was the only solution I could come up with, too. I thought there might be some fancy way to obtain the hostname, but I guess there is no way the server can know its own address unless there is HTTP context.

Comment: Yes, you will need a configuration since there is no request context. The same is true to other frameworks ([Rails](http://goo.gl/dmn8UX), per instance).